# TinyMCE Error - content cannot be displayed in an a frame

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE control on my ASPX.NET page. When the user clicks the "find" button on the control:
[image]

The find 'pop-up' appears with the error "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"
[image]

The puzzling thing is that for most users, the div/pop-up shows up fine (with the exact same browser version, IE8). Clearing cache and temporary internet files does not appear to resolve the issue.

This item is in the system.webserver node of the web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I am unable to reproduce, hitting the same website and performing the same action.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the tinymce config parameter [dialog_type](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3adialog_type):

```
dialog_type: 'modal'
```

Using modal dialogues the browsers won't have to open new windows.

Comment: I dont see dialog_mode as a configuration option, and 'modal' is not one of the options for the 'mode' configuration option.